# How to write in bias with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw, technical-drawing

Hello I wish to write on an image respecting the initial orientation of the text.

As you can see, the initial lettering of the letters is vertical but they follow the direction of the object.

With the use of sloped, I can write along a path but the letters are then tilted.

How to do?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `yslant` and `transform shape`:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  % for the middle of a segment (only for the demo code)
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yslant=0.5]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5,3);

\draw (A) -- (A-|B)
      node[midway, transform shape, above] {The quick brown fox}
      node[midway, transform shape, below, text width=5em, align=center]
        {jumped over the lazy dog.}
      -- (B) node[midway, transform shape, right] {$Ax = B$}
      -- (A|-B) -- cycle;

\node[transform shape] at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]
  {example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By default, node contents are not subject to transformations (as the one defined by `yslant=0.5` here). It is the `transform shape` option that makes the transformation apply to node contents. Of course, if you want `transform shape` to be applied to *all nodes*, you can start the picture with:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[yslant=0.5, nodes={transform shape}]
```

For more fine-grained control, you can use a `scope` environment, as in:

```latex
\begin{scope}[nodes={transform shape}]
  \node at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {\includegraphics[width=2cm] {example-image-duck}};
\end{scope}
```

If we use this and apply `transform shape` to none of the other nodes of this picture, the output becomes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tikz`'s `3d` library, see the [`pgf` manual v3.1.5b](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) §40

For example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);

\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0.5,transform shape]
    \node (0,0) {S};
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0.5,transform shape]
    \node (0,0) {S};
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0.5,transform shape]
    \node (0,0) {S};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]